# How to write unit jest test for Angular Component without TestBed?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am very new to jest testing and I am very confused on why all my tests are failing.

If you know of any videos or articles that specifically help with writing jest unit tests for Angular components, service, etc without "TestBed" please let me know.

Here is my code:

voice-details-graph.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'senet-voice-details-graph',
  templateUrl: './voice-details-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./voice-details-graph.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class VoiceDetailsGraphComponent {
  vm$: Observable<IVoiceSummary> = this._voiceDetailsFacade.vm$.pipe(
    map(vm => vm.graphDetails)
  );

  constructor(private _voiceDetailsFacade: VoiceDetailsFacade) {}

  setCdrFilters() {
    this._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions();
  }

  removeHyphen(phone: string) {
    return phone.replace(/-|\s/g, '');
  }
}
```

voice-details-graph.component.spec.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { VoiceDetailsGraphComponent } from './voice-details-graph.component';

@Injectable()
class MockService {}

describe('VoiceDetailsGraphComponent', () => {
  let component: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new VoiceDetailsGraphComponent(new MockService() as any);
  });

  it('should run #constructor()', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run #setCdrFilters()', async () => {
    component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions = jest.fn();
    component.setCdrFilters();
    expect(component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should run #removeHyphen()', async () => {
    const input = '1-800-999-9999';
    const output = '18009999999';
    component.phone.replace = jest.fn();
    expect(component.removeHyphen(input)).toEqual(output);
    expect(component.phone.replace.toHaveBeenCalled());
  });
});
```

Failures:

```
 FAIL   senet-voice  libs/senet/voice/src/lib/features/voice-details/voice-details-graph/voice-details-graph.component.spec.ts (11.104 s)
  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #constructor()

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

      13 | })
      14 | export class VoiceDetailsGraphComponent {
    > 15 |   vm$: Observable<IVoiceSummary> = this._voiceDetailsFacade.vm$.pipe(
         |                                                                 ^
      16 |     map(vm => vm.graphDetails)
      17 |   );
      18 | 

  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #constructor()

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      13 | 
      14 |   it('should run #constructor()', () => {
    > 15 |     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
         |                       ^
      16 |   });
      17 | 
      18 |   it('should run #setCdrFilters()', async () => {

  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #setCdrFilters()

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

      13 | })
      14 | export class VoiceDetailsGraphComponent {
    > 15 |   vm$: Observable<IVoiceSummary> = this._voiceDetailsFacade.vm$.pipe(
         |                                                                 ^
      16 |     map(vm => vm.graphDetails)
      17 |   );
      18 | 

  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #setCdrFilters()

    TypeError: Cannot read property '_voiceDetailsFacade' of undefined

      17 | 
      18 |   it('should run #setCdrFilters()', async () => {
    > 19 |     component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions = jest.fn();
         |               ^
      20 |     component.setCdrFilters();
      21 |     expect(component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions).toHaveBeenCalled();
      22 |   });

  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #removeHyphen()

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

      13 | })
      14 | export class VoiceDetailsGraphComponent {
    > 15 |   vm$: Observable<IVoiceSummary> = this._voiceDetailsFacade.vm$.pipe(
         |                                                                 ^
      16 |     map(vm => vm.graphDetails)
      17 |   );
      18 | 

  ● VoiceDetailsGraphComponent › should run #removeHyphen()

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined

      25 |     const input = '1-800-999-9999';
      26 |     const output = '18009999999';
    > 27 |     component.phone.replace = jest.fn();
         |               ^
      28 |     expect(component.removeHyphen(input)).toEqual(output);
      29 |     expect(component.phone.replace.toHaveBeenCalled());
      30 |   });
```

Comment: If you're new to testing, why do you think it's a good idea to test without testbed? It actually isn't. You leave DI part untested this way and is on your own on replicating how the real thing works. `vm$` is expected on component construction. You don't have it.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha It's because we do not care to test the service here only the component. The service has it's own spec file.

Comment: @EstusFlask Where I work we do not need Testbed quote from docs: "NOTE: It's important to point out here that both the Angular CLI and third party tool generates the spec file using the TestBed module from Angular. This module is useful if we were going to write Integration Tests with the HTML / UI but since Integration Tests are written by the QA Team (see "Component HTML / UI Testing" section) this module isn't needed and instead going can be removed in favor of a simpler approach. In fact, leaving this TestBed module in your test file can dramatically increase unit testing times."

Comment: Because the constructor needs to have x number of arguments - it just mocks an "argument"... if I do not do this then I get a linter error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my solution:

I needed to add a mock object with the vm$ observable obj into the beforeEach function.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { VoiceDetailsGraphComponent } from './voice-details-graph.component';

describe('VoiceDetailsGraphComponent', () => {
  let component: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockFacade = {
      vm$: of({}),
    };
    component = new VoiceDetailsGraphComponent(mockFacade as any);
  });

  it('should run #constructor()', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run #setCdrFilters()', async () => {
    component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions = jest.fn();
    component.setCdrFilters();
    expect(
      component._voiceDetailsFacade.setCDRInitialOptions
    ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should run #removeHyphen()', async () => {
    const input = '1-800-999-9999';
    const output = '18009999999';
    expect(component.removeHyphen(input)).toEqual(output);
  });
});
```